# не удается получить данные в combobox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=d_base;");
                //string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM d_base.`devices_type`";
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `devices_type`;", conn);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    name.Items.Add(reader.GetString("TypeName"));
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Уточните что идет не так. Вы получаете сообщение об ошибке или получаете пустой список в комбобоксе или что?

Comment: Я получаю пустой список

Comment: Рекомендую добавить тег `winforms` или `wpf` к вопросу.